# AVAssetWriter without re-encoding

Tags: avfoundation

I want to write a mov h264 video file using the AVAssetWriter. My input video stream for the AVAssetWriterInput is already encoded as h264. How should I configurate the AVAssetWriter in order to write the h264 stream to the file (without re-encoding)?

```
    NSDictionary* videoSettings = [NSDictionary
    dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:AVVideoCodecH264, AVVideoCodecKey,
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt: width], AVVideoWidthKey,
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt: height], AVVideoHeightKey, nil];

    auto videoWriterInput = [[AVAssetWriterInput alloc] initWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo
                                                       outputSettings:videoSettings];
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the outputSettings to `nil`.